# MySQL NOT IN query only including result that I want to exclude

Tags: mysql

Query:

```
SELECT * 
from t1
INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.item_id = t2.item_id
WHERE t1.item_id NOT IN
(Select t2.item_id from t2)
```

Basically, I'm trying to exclude all results with an item_id in the t2 table, but it is only including results with an item_id in the t2 table.  What am I missing here....

Thanks for any and all responses!

Comment: Thanks everyone for the tips and correct responses!  It all came down to a logic level issue after I had the right method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You join and then exclude everything :/

At least that's what sql says [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2a4f8/1)

Try something like this:

```
SELECT 
    item_id
FROM 
    t1
WHERE 
    item_id NOT IN (SELECT item_id from t2)
```

as in [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2a4f8/3).

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised you are getting anything with that query since you seem to be excluding anything you would have included through the join.  Try changing your query to this:

```
SELECT * from t1
WHERE item_id NOT IN (SELECT item_id from t2)
```

Comment: Thanks much! Found out I had a logic issue with where I was putting the "Not In" statement (since the query is a bit more complicated than posted.  Pretty new to sql, so thank you very much for the feedback detailing that I didn't have to join the tables to relate them.

Answer (score 0):

This will select items from T1 that do NOT have a corresponding entry in T2. I think this is what you wanted.

```
SELECT * 
from t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.item_id = t2.item_id
WHERE t2.item_id IS NULL
```